How to properly access a map value?
I was trying to solve Leetcode problem #697: Degree of an Array. I created a map to store <int, int> values. I saw examples where people were using a element.first and element.second line to retreive the values stored in the map. However, I get an error saying there is no member named second in the map. I want to know if there is a built-in function to retreive a second element from a map, and if there is a standard way to do this.
class Solution {
public:
    int findShortestSubArray(vector<int>& nums) {
        
        //nums -> array of integers
        // step 1 : iterate through the array and find the degree, I would do this by iterating through nums and storing the value of each number in a hashmap
        // The hash map will store the number, first occ and last occ
            // The key will be the number and the values stored will be first and sec occurance.

        
        unordered_map<int,int> firstOcc;
        unordered_map<int,int> secondOcc;
        unordered_map<int,int> count;

        // Go through the array and collect the first/last occ and the frequency
        for (int i =0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {   
            int currNum = nums[i];
            //If we've never come across this number before, update the first position.
            if(count[i]==0)
            {
                firstOcc[currNum] = i;
            }

            count[currNum]++;
            secondOcc[currNum] = i;
        }

        //Iterate through the count map and find the highest count.
        int highestCount =0;
        for (auto& i : count)
        {
            if (count.second > highestCount)
            {
                highestCount=count[i];
            }
        }

        //Now go through and figure out which has the shortest length
        int minLength = 0;
        for (auto i :count)
        {
            if (count[i]==highestCount)
            {
                int length = secondOcc[i]-firstOcc[i]+1;
                minLength = min(minLength, length);
            }
        }

        return minLength;
    }
};

Here I was trying to retrieve the y value stored at count[x][y] in the count map.
if (count.second > highestCount)
{
     highestCount=count[i];
}

This is the error I get:
Line 33: Char 23: error: no member named 'second' in 'std::unordered_map<int, int>'
    33 |             if (count.second > highestCount)      


first and second are not members of any type of map. They are members of pair, which is what you get for each element when you iterate over a map.

std::unorderd_map.  Instead of going to Leetcode to learn C++ (Leetcode is meant for experienced C++ programmers), I suggest you start by writing small programs first, so that you know exactly how to use a std::unordered_map.  You do realize that the type that is stored in the map is a std::pair?

count is a map, it contains several pairs of values, so  count.second makes no sense because although it's asking for the 'second' value it doesn't specify which of the many pairs it wants to get the second value from. If element is an element of the map (i.e. one of the pairs) then element.second makes perfect sense.

"How to properly access a map value?" If you have to ask questions like this it is time to take one step back. Forget about competitive coding for now and first learn C++ itself  (e.g. learncpp.com) and learn where to look for C++ information (e.g. cppreference.com).   Competitive coding should come after that, also because the coding habits you will pickup are really bad for you getting a job later, because there you should be able write readable/maintainable code and you should be able to follow the C++ core guidelines.

In your 1st count iteration loop, count is the unordered_map itself, not an element of count, so this expression is wrong:
if (count.second > highestCount)
The map doesn't have a second member. But the elements of the map do.
Also, you have several other mistakes that will lead to bad  behavior at runtime:

In your nums iteration loop, i is a vector index, but your count keys are not vector indexes, so this expression is wrong:
if(count[i]==0)

In both of your count iteration loops, i is an element (a key+value std::pair) of count, not a key of count, so all of these expressions are wrong:
highestCount=count[i];
if (count[i]==highestCount)
int length = secondOcc[i]-firstOcc[i]+1;


Try this instead:
class Solution {
public:
    int findShortestSubArray(vector<int>& nums) {
        
        //nums -> array of integers
        // step 1 : iterate through the array and find the degree, I would do this by iterating through nums and storing the value of each number in a hashmap
        // The hash map will store the number, first occ and last occ
        // The key will be the number and the values stored will be first and sec occurance.
        
        unordered_map<int,int> firstOcc;
        unordered_map<int,int> secondOcc;
        unordered_map<int,int> count;

        // Go through the array and collect the first/last occ and the frequency
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
        {
            int currNum = nums[i];
            //If we've never come across this number before, update the first position.
            if(count[currNum]==0)
            {
                firstOcc[currNum] = i;
            }

            count[currNum]++;
            secondOcc[currNum] = i;
        }

        /* alternatively:

        int i = 0;
        for (int currNum : nums)
        {
            //If we've never come across this number before, update the first position.
            if(count[currNum]==0)
            {
                firstOcc[currNum] = i;
            }

            count[currNum]++;
            secondOcc[currNum] = i;
            ++i;
        }
        */

        //Iterate through the count map and find the highest count.
        int highestCount = 0;
        for (auto& elem : count)
        {
            if (elem.second > highestCount)
            {
                highestCount = elem.second;
            }
        }

        //Now go through and figure out which has the shortest length
        int minLength = 0;
        for (auto& elem : count)
        {
            if (elem.second == highestCount)
            {
                int length = secondOcc[elem.first]-firstOcc[elem.first]+1;
                minLength = min(minLength, length);
            }
        }

        return minLength;
    }
};

